How to understand "on the up and up" in "...about to get a delivery that's truly on the up and up..."
At the begining of Silicon Valley company Matternet launches drone delivery service

In the heart of Silicon Valley, 64-year-old Brian Drummond is about to
get a delivery that's truly on the up and up.

What does "on the up and up" mean?
"honest or legal" doesn't seem like an appropriate explanation.

Google says 1: British = becoming more successful ("his career is certainly on the up and up").  2: North American = honest or legal ("investigators wanted to make sure everything we did was on the up and up"). I've never encountered that US definition, which clearly conflicts with the far more common on the level. Might that be Google's AI hallucinating?

It's a pun. A joke. So it's not surprising if it's using the term in an inaccurate way. In case you can't work it out, "up" refers to the sky, where drones are.

Looking at COCA, in the US the legal sense is more common, but there are examples meaning successful: "Ditching money-losing stocks is clearly a better move than borrowing ... Everything in your portfolio on the up and up?" (Money magazine, US publication) "It does always seem that everyone else is on the up and up in success." (Orange County-based photography blog) "Joining exclusive clubs or going to exclusive parties gives them an easy way to boost their profiles or see who's on the up and up." (Blog by LA-based journalist)

Some of those are puns, and others probably malapropisms by people who didn't realize that what they had seen were puns.

@FumbleFingers  "on the level" = legit = honest/legal. Not sure why you think you've never seen it.   Unless you mean something different by "on the level" than that phrase is used in AmE.   There's something about this operation that doesn't seem on the up and up and on the level. I doubt it's legit. I've never seen a customer go through that door in ten years. Maybe a moneylaundering operation.

@TimR: I said I've never seen on the up and up used to mean "honest or legal". Which unfamiliar definition was obviously also found by the OP, who can't see how it would apply in the cited context. My specific point is that the usage clearly conflicts with on the level (also AmE rather than BrE)...

...So even though I can find examples of the "honest" meaning in Google Books (including this definition contrasting BrE/AmE), I still think it's potentially confusing, and I would advise learners to avoid it.

@FumbleFingers   "On the up and up", meaning legitimate, legal, honest,  above-board, "legit", "not 'shady'", does not conflict with "on the level", which has those very same meanings in AmE.

@TimR: I'm surprised you don't seem to recognize a conflict between on the level and on the up and up meaning the same thing, even allowing for the fact that as an American you presumably use both expressions with similar if not identical meanings. I still think learners should avoid it, since it will be baffling to most Brits.

Websters New International Dictionary (1934): https://www.google.com/books/edition/Webster_s_New_International_Dictionary_o/WQ41Dog6gcAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22on+the+up+and+up%22&pg=PA2799&printsec=frontcover

@FumbleFingers  I recognize that ascent and on the level seem like different things in spatial terms. I'm just surprised that you had never seen the definition.

@TimR: I notice even your Webster (American) dictionary gives the "honest" definition second (after the more natural "ongoing improvement" sense). But the full OED definition defines it as 4.a.
1863–
Honest(ly), straightforward(ly), ‘on the level’. Originally and chiefly U.S. with no hint of irony. I can only guess it alludes to upright moral character - no dictionaries give an etymology.

But this is from a question on ELU about the origin - it's an example of a phrase that many people use one way, and many another, with people in either group not knowing of the other.

@FumbleFingers  That  1934 edition is an "international" edition of the Webster's dictionary. Its editor was a Scot.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Allan_Neilson

Here delivery doesn't refer to that particular order he has made.

... a delivery that's truly on the up and up

means this mode of delivery is going to be more and more common, or the frequency of such usage is expected to go up and up.

When not "reduplicated", the standard expression is [thing becoming more prominent / successful] is on the rise. But idiomatically we rarely use non-reduplicated on the up, and we never say something is on the rise and rise.

Thanks, @FumbleFingers.  Agreed. On the rise has lots of hits.  There’re no on the up in this sense; those I went through are false positives.  on the ...

It seems to me the more obvious (if painfully forced) intended pun is that it's a drone, which goes up. Especially with the "flying off the shelves, quite literally" joke seconds later. The journalistic-dad-joke is reaching for the most basic material, not the speculation of success, but the "Look, up in the sky; it's a bird, it's a plane..."

@AndyBonner: It's not really relevant that it's a pun (unless the OP was asking why "truly"). Or are you suggesting the usage is sufficiently unusual that it wouldn't have occurred without the pun?
